# How to automatically start in Normal mode?

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode

I am using zsh on Mac and noticed that whenever I start vim, it always starts in insert mode. I use vim to inspect files more often than to edit. I tried adding `set noinsertmode` but it didn't have any effect.

How can I switch to normal mode upon start?

Comment: I'm voting to close that as a duplicate of [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file) because vim default behavior is to start in insert mode and what you are observing is most likely the effect of a configuration you added to your vimrc. Or -but this is less likely- a consequence of how you invoke vim (maybe a parameter you give it or a bash alias you created and didn't realized it would have this side effect)

Comment: I guess this is a typo: vim default behavior is to start in _normal_ mode

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As @statox says, this isn't default, and the debug link might help you find the issue. In particular, if this isn't happening with, say, `vim -u NONE` or `vim -u DEFAULTS` or `vim --clean`, you probably have a configuration issue. It could also be a parameter or alias, as mentioned.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble True, if I switch off the plugins, `vim` starts in NORMAL mode. Thanks!